# Which apk will beta users get if beta apk is older that official apk?

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing, google-play-console

I have set up a Google Play beta program for my Android app. Imagine the following scenario:

- I publish apk1 as a beta release with `versionCode 1`
- Beta users install this beta release
- I publish apk2 as an **official** release build with `versionCode 2`

Will beta users be offered apk2 by Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...your alpha APKs should have the highest version codes, followed by
>   beta, and finally production.
>
> - ...
> - If a production APK is uploaded with a higher version code than an alpha or beta APK, **some or all of your alpha and beta users will
>     install the production APK, instead of APKs of the testing tracks**.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en#version_codes

Comment: I verified that Google Play in this case displays a warning: "Shadowed by production.
To be available to all testers, APKs on this track need to have a higher version code than production APKs."